# Appcelerator - Android failed to package application, duplicate file

Tags: android, facebook, titanium, appcelerator, simulator

Having a load of issues with Appcelerator at the moment, random error messages at every turn, but I know that comes with the territory.

Today's hurdle is testing out the Facebook integration for my app and I'm testing on a vanilla project created by the studio.

When I go to test the application I get the following error:

```
[ERROR] :  Failed to package application:
[ERROR] :  
[ERROR] :  /Users/auhjbe0/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/CleanProject/build/android/res/drawable-hdpi-v4/com_facebook_button_like_icon_selected.png: error: Duplicate file.
[ERROR] :  /Users/auhjbe0/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/CleanProject/build/android/res/drawable-hdpi/com_facebook_button_like_icon_selected.png: Original is here. The version qualifier may be implied.
```

Nothing special with the project, it's just a basic setup with the `tiapp.xml` changes and `facebook.module` added?

Any ideas?

Comment: Getting the same! :(

Answer (score 1):

See this ticket https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/MOD-2283  But even though it says it’s resolved…it’s not.  You have to download the facebook module 5.2.0 from github and place it locally in your project (modules).  The facebook module 5.2.0 in the Ti sdk distribution fails the build.