# Titanium: Unable to run application after upgrading to SDK 5.5.0 - Facebook issue

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-facebook

I've updated to from SDK 5.4.0 to SDK 5.5.0 (didn't change anything at code) and tried to run on my Android device and got the following error message. I'm using the Facebook module.

```
[ERROR] :  Failed to package application:
[ERROR] :  
[ERROR] :  /Users/ophir/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/MyApp/build/android/res/drawable-hdpi-v4/com_facebook_button_like_icon_selected.png: error: Duplicate file.
[ERROR] :  /Users/ophir/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/MyApp/build/android/res/drawable-hdpi/com_facebook_button_like_icon_selected.png: Original is here. The version qualifier may be implied.
```

I tried cleaning my project - didn't help.

Advice?

**EDIT**

Now if I try to go back to SDK 5.4.0 it also shows the same error. This is a project that was run without a problem just a week ago...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Appcelerator - Android failed to package application, duplicate file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39589842/appcelerator-android-failed-to-package-application-duplicate-file)

Comment: Other question has a solution, basically grab the facebook modules from github (https://github.com/appcelerator-modules/ti.facebook/releases)